# Java - How to create a Class<Map<Object,List<Object>>> object

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, casting

I'm sorry if this is a noob question. I have a method which takes a Class object with the generic type as a parameter. I am able to do the following:

```
Class cs = Map.class;
```

but when I pass this I get an "NoSuchMethodException" since the method is declared:

```
public void doSomething(Class<Map<Object, List<Object>>> theclass){
...     
}
```

I have tried to cast it like this:

```
Class cs = (Class<Map<Object, List<Object>>>)(Class<?>)Map.class;
```

but I still get the same exception.

Is there a way to do this?

I cannot post the full code here but I have reproduced the error:
The application is actually using reflection. I can not post the original code here but I have reproduced the exception:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = null;
        try {
            c = Class.forName("Second");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String m = "doSomething";
        Method method = null;
        Class cs = Map.class;
        try{
            method = c.getMethod(m, cs);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Second{
    public static void doSomething(Class<Map<Object, List<Object>>> theclass){
        System.out.println("HERE I AM!");   
    }   
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Second.doSomething(java.util.Map)
    at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:283)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:825)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Comment: You're trying to fight type erasure.

Comment: check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: What statement is throwing the exception?

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the exception to be thrown.  Simply passing the wrong `Class` object as a method parameter is not going to cause it to happen.  You must be doing something else.

Comment: Note that `public void doSomething(Class<Map<Object, List<Object>>> theclass)` is not a useful method signature, since it requires that `theClass` be *exactly* the class denoted `Map<Object, List<Object>>`, so there is only one non-`null` value that could ever be passed to that method. Maybe you wanted to write `public void doSomething(Class<? extends Map<Object, List<Object>>> theclass)` (which would also accept subclasses)?

Comment: A `Class` represents a class or interface, such as a `Map`. To represent a parameterised type, you need something like `ParameterizedType`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html (But your issue is you are using `Map.class` instead of `Class.class`, and some raw types and reflection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I have changed the following line:

```
method = c.getMethod(m, cs);
```

to:

```
method = c.getMethod(m, cs.getClass());
```

Now it works!

Comment: `cs.getClass()` could better be written `Class.class`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline only if `cs` is a class literal, otherwise `getClass` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing such casting, I think you're fighting against the type system that's designed to help you. For starters,

```
Class cs = Map.class;
```

is a *raw* type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for more info). Have you tried instantiating a class of your required `Map` type, and passing the class of *that* to your function ?

e.g.

```
(new HashMap<Object, List<Object>>()).getClass();
```

Note: as *ruakh* as noted in the comments above, you'd have to pass an instance of the Map interface, and as such that method declaration above would prohibit this. Basically there's a fundamental API design issue here!

Comment: But the method, as listed, wouldn't accept such an argument, due to invariance. (See my comment above.)